# Struts list validation

Tags: list, validation, drop-down-menu, struts2

I have a struts2 select

```
<s:select list="country" listKey="referenceId" listValue="referenceDesc" 
  headerKey="0" headerValue="Select an option" 
  name="selectedCountry[%{#status.index}]"/>.
```

Now I can see three drop-downlist which is dynamically generated for three users, my question is how to validate for each person that country is selected in validation.xml. I heard about visitor validator which I feel complex for this scenario, Can some one let me know how to get this make working.

Comment: I'd just put something in a `validate()` method to make sure each has a value.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I should have added more information to it. Above this select I have a radio button question yes or no. If user selects yes then I should validate for select drop-down I mean user should choose some value from drop-down, if not I have to throw message. How to achieve this?

Comment: The same way: this is validation I'd probably handle in Java. There's no default mechanism for validating a collection in S2, although it could be written, I suppose.

Comment: What did you try to do, could you provide the xml?